# VSO problems adding users

Tags: azure-devops

I have a team project in VSO with 5 basic users. The problem is,  only I can see the actual code and code repository while others can oly see boards and things like that. When they trie to access the repository it sais that they do not have permissions or error in server. All of them have all permissions which I added in project "Security" place. What can be the problem? Also, I cannot see them in "capcity" settings on the sprint settings. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, tt sounds like they aren't part of the team so they aren't getting the appropriate permissions.  Here's a walkthrough for how to add new team members:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/add-team-members-vs.  Did this help?

[image: Adding Team Members in Visual Studio Online]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the problem is, that those members are shown as team members in the project settings but in the actual project they are "invisible". What's more, they can see the work/rooms sections, but they cannot see the code section.

Comment: for some reason, the project is crashed :D I created a new project and everything works like a charm, but thanks anyway

Comment: @DainiusKavoliūnas OK great.  I'm glad that worked out for you.  Let's call this item closed then.